# elegant way of setting multiple methods to equal another method

Tags: python, methods, assign

I have this method in a class:

```
def do_exit():
  # some task
```

I want to assign a bunch of other methods to `do_exit`, so currently I'm doing this:

```
do_quit = do_exit
do_stop = do_exit
do_finish = do_exit
do_complete = do_exit
do_leave = do_exit
```

This works fine but I'm wondering if there's a better way, especially if I'm going to be doing this a lot.

Comment: How many methods are we talking about here? For 5 assignments, this is *more than fine*.

Comment: I am sorry, as this may seem as inappropriate question. But why is this a problem? Why not simple documentation entry, that there is one `do_exit` method with such name. I am baffled by the idea I can call 5 different names to do the same task. I really like the question, because this is possible to solve in a generic way in python. But it can even turn out to be counter productive, when one sees `do_finish` in one place and `do_quit` in another, in the same context. Usually different names mean different tasks when used in the same context.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might consider making a dictionary to hold your methods. With a defaultdict, you can ensure that `do_exit` is called if it's ever the case that nothing else was slotted in for a particular function name. On the other hand, this might not be very safe or validated against, e.g. spelling errors:

```
from collections import defaultdict
method_dict = defaultdict(lambda: do_exit)

# Try this
method_dict["do_quit"]()
```

Within a class, you could also override `__getattr__` if you'd like. Say, just guessing, that all of these kinds of methods begin with `do` or else maybe the condition is that they end with some synonym of `complete`. You could give the class a class attribute that holds the appropriate convention items and checks for them, and looks them up in `method_dict` as needed.

```
from collections import defaultdict

class Foo(object):
    QUIT_WORDS = ['exit', 'quit', 'stop', 'finish', 'complete', 'leave']

    def __init__(self):
        self.method_dict = defaultdict(lambda: self.do_exit)

    def __getattr__(self, attr):
        if any([attr.endswith("_{}".format(x)) for x in self.QUIT_WORDS]):
            return self.method_dict[attr]
        else:
            return super(Foo, self).__getattribute__(attr)

    def do_exit(self):
        print "Exit!"
```

For example:

```
In [88]: f = Foo()

In [89]: f.do_quit()
Exit!

In [90]: f.do_exit()
Exit!

In [91]: f.do_go_bye_bye()
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-91-2584940dee36> in <module>()
----> 1 f.do_go_bye_bye()

<ipython-input-87-3b0db0bf6a47> in __getattr__(self, attr)
     11             return self.method_dict[attr]
     12         else:
---> 13             return super(Foo, self).__getattribute__(attr)
     14 
     15
```

Comment: Awesome solution. I modified it a bit to fit my use case. Can you tell me if there are any possible issues with my modification: http://ideone.com/Cjpcve Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Your code is actually dangerous: if you subclass your initial class, you'll get unexpected behavior. Consider the following:

```
class Foo(object):
    def m1(self):
        print "Hello!"

    m2 = m1


class Bar(Foo):
    def m1(self):
        print "World!"

# prints "World!", as expected
Bar().m1()

# prints "Hello!", because Bar.m2 is Foo.m2 is Foo.m1, *not* Bar.m1
Bar().m2()
```

Unfortunately, the only *simple* solution to your use case that doesn't break inheritance is to define each method manually, with a `def foo(self): return self.bar()` type of construct.

Answer (score -1):

You can do:

```
do_quit = do_stop = do_finish = do_complete = do_leave = do_exit
```

Comment: Sorry but I don't think this makes any difference. OP wants something else.